# How to transform this mapping into a function?

Tags: vimscript, functions

So I made this mapping

```
"%p$?/<CR>d$V"uy:cd <C-r>u<CR>
```

That is the crux of the mapping but it leaves artifacts in the current file, that is part of what I want to avoid.

My attempt at creating a function is more or less a direct translation thus far.

My problem is that I really don't know vimscript very well.
Any help is appreciated, even some good documentation, or a pointer to relevant help files in vimhelp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your mapping properly it is used to get the directory containing the current buffer and then `cd` to this directory.

You say that your mapping leaves characters in your current buffer and that is why you want to use a function. I think that using a function here is not necessary you just need to write a better mapping. By "better mapping" I mean a mapping which will use built-in features and will not have to modify your buffer just to change the working directory.

For example something like this would do the job:

```
nnoremap <yourkey> :execute "cd " . expand('%:h')<CR>
```

Let's break the executed command down:

```
execute "cd " . expand('%:h')

execute                         will take a string and execute it as a command
        "cd "                   is the beginning of the command you want to execute
              .                 allows to concatenate two strings
                expand('   ')   will be used to tranform a file name as we want
                        %       is the current file name
                         :h     tells to expand() to return only the directory of the file
```

You can try to use directly in the command line `:echo expand('%:h')` to understand better what's happening.

Here are some help topics you might want to read:

- [`:h :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3aexecute)
- [`:h expand()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29)

---

*Edit* As @LuHermitte pointed out in the comments, while the previous mappings works using `execute` and `expand()` is clearly overkill since the command line can substitute `%:h` on its own. So the mapping should be

```
nnoremap <silent> <yourkey> :cd %:h<CR>
```

(Use `<silent>` to avoid echoing the mapping in the command line)

Comment: Thanks that did the job. Not only did this solve my problem also pointed to reference materiel.

Comment: `:cd %:h` should be enough in that case.

Comment: @LucHermitte Yes clearly I don't know why I overthought this one!

Comment: Well I appreiciate the effort either way :)